# PHP: JWT based authentication

Tags: php, authentication, jwt

Thinking about JWT token based authentication in PHP, I realise that when used in building an API it will be impossible to load the same page in different tabs of the same browser, as each request to the server will require the token to authenticate the user which the new tab does not have.

The project I am currently working on does not require me to use cookies, authentication is supposed to be purely token based.

Am I missing something or is that the way it ought to work?

PS: I am 2 days old in JWT authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is supposed to be done using cookie+token. If you store your token in cookie, you can use it in other tabs according to the valid domain. It is still token based authentication, you should just pay attention to cookie security.

Comment: hmm, I see, so because what I am developing is an API I do not need to bother about sessions or cookies, but the validity of the data sent to the user

Comment: Just dont use php session, set your jwt token to cookie based on your domain with an expiration, which is `httponly` and `secure` and always use ssl.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to share the token via some other mechanism such as local storage or a cookie which can be *exchanged* for a token then yes, that is correct.

Keep in mind though that localStorage has to be manually deleted so it's probably not the best mechanism for this.